# Highlight bar chart color above geom_hline

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bar plot with the mean as a horizontal line and would like to color the bars that go above the average, but only the top portion of the bar. Is this possible?

```
test <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(avg = mean(Sepal.Length))

ggplot(test, aes(x = Species, y = avg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(test$avg))
```

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best solution, but it works:

```
test <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(avg = mean(Sepal.Length))
test2 <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate(avg, avg = ifelse(avg > mean(avg), mean(avg), avg))

ggplot(test, aes(x = Species, y = avg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", data=test, fill="red") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", data=test2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(test$avg))
```

[image]